# Value error in Timeseries forecasting while reading csv file

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, valueerror

Quick question for an issue I haven't managed to solve quickly:

I'm working with a .csv file and can't seem to find a simple way to convert strings to floats. Here's my code

data = pd.read_csv('E:/Python.Directory/Sunspots.csv', usecols = [1, 2])

mod=ARIMA(list(data['Monthly Mean Total Sunspot Number']), order=(1,0,1))

res=mod.fit()

pred = res.predict()

**print(r2_score(data, pred)**

Last line returns value error. I already tried a few code snippets from earlier value error posts here. But does not seem to work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the actual traceback. It's not clear to me how it would get to that point if you hadn't got the right dtype

Comment: And what is `r2_score` in your code? Your parentheses are also unbalanced.

Comment: if you are looking to convert the columns and read them as float rather than string, you can use ```dtype``` parameter in read_csv, this already answered on the stackoverflow. check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: If the traceback is indicating that the problem arises during execution of that last line then I think you should probably tag your question with 'arima'. I don't think this is a Python issue per se

Comment: Yes its Arima model.r2_score is R2 score in errors for regression. dtype parametr in read_csv do not work, I tried.